# Adding to sortedlist in a parallel for loop error: ArgumentException was unhandled by user code error

Tags: c#, collections, sortedlist, parallel.foreach

```
items.AsParallel().ForAll(i =>
{
string[] splitter = i.Split('\t');
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Converted: {0} - {1} - {2}", splitter[0], splitter[1], splitter[2]));
productList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(splitter[0]), splitter[1] + "\t" + splitter[2]);
// the above line is where the error prompts
});
```

"items" is a ConcurrentStack that has a value of product id, name and details separated by a tab.

Ex:

items[0] = 1\tshampoo\tcleans your hair

I have a parallel loop that splits the items into 3 array indexes (splitter) then adds it to "productList", "productList" is a SortedList. When I add it the splitted value to productList, the id should now be the key and the name + details is the value.

Ex:

splitter [0] = 1; splitter[1] = shampoo; splitter[2] = cleans your hair

productList[0] key = 1; productList[1] value = shampoo\tcleans your hair

The weird part is that sometimes the program runs flawlessly and sometimes it prompts an error ArgumentException was unhandled by user code error. This is the error's details:
"Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.". Does using a parallel have something to do with this? The thing is I have to use the parallel to execute the loop much faster.

Note: data is only a sample.

Update:
I tried changing string[] splitter with var splitter and got this error: "Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.". I checked the productList in Immediate Windows and some data are added before this error showed up.

Comment: there might be two different problems with your code: 1)no one guarantees the thread safety of sortedlist 2) are you sure its not the `Convert.ToInt32` that throws the exception? P.S just for the record, im not sure you can take for granted this code will execute faster in a parallel execution. At the end it comes down to locking the same collection (productList), which will be your bottle neck in this case.

Comment: Yes, it might be the adding to the sortedlist in a parallel for loop. Sometimes the program worked so I think it has nothing to do with the int conversion. I tried checking the contents of productList(the sortedlist) in the Immediate Window when the error occurred, there are already values added to the productList before the error showed up.

Comment: Any time you are going to make changes to a data structure that isn't thread safe in a multi-threaded scenario, you need to lock it, make your changes, and then unlock it. If you don't, it is possible to have 2 or more threads trying to edit it at the same time, which usually leads to problems such as you describe. Also, you need to examine your data structure: is it safe to allow it to be read by multiple threads ALL the time? If not (and it isn't if you have to lock it to edit it), then you need to lock it just to read it, to guarantee it isn't being altered while you read it.